# Rails: New entry not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

I'm having a problem when trying to save a new entry into my database. On submit, a project should get saved to a project table, and a technology/technologies within that project get saved to a relationship table.

**UPDATE** Code has been updated after a number of changes

**Heres my new action:**

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

@all_technols = Technol.all
tech_ids = params[:technols][:id].reject(&:blank?) unless params[:technols].nil?


@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build





#@project_technol = Projecttechnol.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

**Create action:**

```
    def create
    @all_technols = Technol.all
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

@technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])




params[:technol].each_value do |tech|

technology = Technol.find_by_tech(tech.strip)

@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technology.id)

end


    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @project.project_owner = params[:new_project_owner] unless params[:new_project_owner].blank?
    @project.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?
    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
    @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
    @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my 3 models:

**Project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :edited_first_name, :edited_last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date,  :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech , :technols

validates_presence_of :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :end_date,  :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary




has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :technols, :through => :projecttechnols


def self.like(text); "%#{text}%"; end

  def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_techs_ids, search_business_div, search_project_owner,  search_status, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords)
    # start with a scoped query, to apply more scopes on it afterwards
    _projects = Project.scoped 
    # then, for each of the parameters, apply the scope only if present
    if search_client.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['client LIKE ?', like(search_client)] 
    end
    if search_industry.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['industry LIKE ?', like(search_industry)]
    end
    if search_role.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['role LIKE ?', like(search_role)]
    end

#_projects = _projects.joins(:technols).
 #             where("technols.id" => search_techs_ids)



#_projects = _projects.joins(:projecttechnols).where("projecttechnols.id" => search_techs_ids)


if search_techs_ids.present?
_projects = _projects.joins(:technols).where("technols.id" => search_techs_ids)
end



    if search_business_div.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['business_div LIKE ?', like(search_business_div)]
    end
    if search_project_owner.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['project_owner LIKE ?', like(search_project_owner)]
    end

     if search_status.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['status LIKE ?', like(search_status)]
    end



todays_date = DateTime.now.to_date

if !search_start_date_A.blank? or !search_start_date_B.blank?
    search_start_date_A = Date.parse(search_start_date_A).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    search_start_date_B = Date.parse(search_start_date_B).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    todays_date = nil
    search_start_date_dd = nil

    end

if search_start_date_dd.blank?
    todays_date = nil
end


if search_start_date_A.present? or search_start_date_B.present?

      _projects = _projects.where [' DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B]
    end


                if search_start_date_dd.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', search_start_date_dd, todays_date]
    end




    if search_keywords.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['keywords LIKE ?', like(search_keywords)]
    end
    # now you have applied only the present scopes. return the result, and watch 
    # the query as it executes.
    _projects
  end


def self.paginated_for_index(projects_per_page, current_page)
    paginate(:per_page => projects_per_page, :page => current_page)
  end

end
```

**technol.rb**

```
class Technol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tech

has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :projects, :through => :projecttechnols
end
```

**projecttechnol.rb**

```
class Projecttechnol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :technol_id

belongs_to :technol
belongs_to :project
end
```

and here is part of the new view, which I think is causing the problem:

```
<div class="tech">

<% common_techs = [['Mainframe'],['UNIX'],['Windows Servers'],['Networking'],['CISCO'], ['Win7'], ['Telephony'], ['Web services'], ['Website'], ['Cloud'], ['Virtualisation'], ['Data Centre']] %>
 <% db_techs = Technol.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq %>

<% all_tech = common_techs + db_techs %>


<%= form_for(@technol) do |tech| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= tech.label :tech %><br />
    <%= tech.text_field :tech %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

When I click the submit button to create a new project, I get this error:

```
    RuntimeError in ProjectsController#create

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:116:in `block in create'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:112:in `each_value'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:112:in `create'
```

These are my params:

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sPyJbgBKTxa9iHWF9r0Gg/0R/v0l0/e8KwXpPebzdus=",
 "project"=>{"project_name"=>"",
 "status"=>"Active",
 "client"=>"",
 "business_div"=>"",
 "project_owner"=>"",
 "start_date"=>"01-10-2012",
 "entry_date"=>"2012-10-03",
 "end_date"=>"09-10-2012",
 "role"=>"",
 "industry"=>"",
 "summary"=>"",
 "lessons_learned"=>"",
 "customer_benifits"=>"",
 "financials"=>"",
 "keywords"=>""},
 "new_client"=>"",
 "new_business_div"=>"",
 "new_project_owner"=>"",
 "technol"=>{"tech"=>"TESTER"},
 "new_role"=>"",
 "new_industry"=>"",
 "commit"=>"Save New Project"}
```

Comment: i think u want to create a project and its related technology object and save both when project is saved. ie u should have a look at "accepts_nested_attributes_for" and http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Yes I do. I have followed the rails cast video, and this is where I am now. Are you able to explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're looking up for value of key "id" in the hash returned by `params[:technols]`. However when you look at that hash `{"tech"=>"Web services"}` there is only one key which is "tech". Hence when you try to do `params[:technol][:id]` you basically get a nil object.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. What do I need to do to change this? The dropdown menus in my new form show all the right technologies, so I don't really understand why I would get a nil object?

Comment: You are not passing id from your view, just name of the technology. So either you rewrite your view to send technology id through to create action or inside create you lookup the technology ids from database using technology name i.e. `params[:technols][:tech].each_value do |tech| technology = Technols.find_by_tech(tech);@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technology.id) ...`

Comment: Still getting the same error message. I have changed my create action. see edit. cheers

Comment: there is a typo in my comment above. It should read `Technol.find_by_tech(tech)` instead of `Technols.find_by_tech(tech)`. And I have assumed presence of a column named `tech` in your table. If your column name where you store technology names is something else then use that `Technol.find_by_<column_name>(tech)`

Comment: I've changed that now. Yes my column name is tech for the Technol table. I'm still getting the same error. Driving me mad :(

Comment: actually you need to write `params[:technol].each_value do |tech|` instead of `params[:technol][:tech].each_value do |tech|`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I now have this error. `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

Comment: well in ruby everything is a object, even nil and error is talking about the object_id of nil which happens to be 4. I can only tell you that much from the error message. You need to post your updated code for me to comment further.

Comment: most likely I suspect that your line `technology = Technols.find_by_tech(tech)` is returning a nil object, so it means there is no row in your Technols table where value of tech column = value you are passing. Perhaps there are spaces in the string you're passing, so inspect the value of your `tech` variable and try `technology = Technols.find_by_tech(tech.strip)`

Comment: I have tried your last suggestion, and nothing changed. I have updated my question with my latest code and error. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Do you have a row where Technols.tech = "TESTER" (notice the case) in your database?

Comment: No TESTER is what i'm trying to submit into the Technols table. As a new technology

Comment: Managed to get it to work. Needed to have `technology = Technol.find_or_create_by_tech(tech.strip)` Thanks for all your help